# Ruby on rails connect to right Postgres DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have developed a website using RoR + Postgresql, migrated it to Heroku using Git. All works well.

Then I imported the website and the databases from Heroku back to local (on another computer). All went well too.

However, I now have 4 databases locally:

`myapp`
`myapp_test`
`myapp_development`
`myapp_production`

When testing my app locally, it turns out it is communicating with myapp_development.

But all my data is in the DB `myapp`.

How do I instruct RoR to use the DB `myapp`?

Comment: if you want to use `myapp` db for your development - just change it in `database.yml` under `development` section.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct - I can provide next solution.
Here is example of **config/database.yml**

```
login: &login
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  username: user_name
  password: password

development:
  <<: *login
  database: db_name_development

test:
  <<: *login
  database: db_name_test

production:
  <<: *login
  database: db_name_production
```

Try to replace:

```
development:
  <<: *login
  database: db_name_development
```

With:

```
development:
  <<: *login
  database: myapp_development
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses database configuration from two sources - `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` and `config/database.yml`.

`ENV['DATABASE_URL']` is an env var that is set in the shell, operating system or when involking the process.

For an example setting `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` to:

```
postgresql://localhost/myapp
```

Would connect to the correct database via postgres. This is how Heroku sets which database your production app connects to.

`config/database.yml` is just a YAML file that is read by ActiveRecord when setting up the database. It contains a hash of hashes - which key is used is determined by `Rails.env` (which is set via `ENV['RAILS_ENV']`).

```
common: &common
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *common # this is YAML syntax to merge this hash with &common
  database: myapp
```

The values in `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` are merged with those from `config/database.yml` but `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` has preceedence.

### A friendly tip:

- Just set the bare minimum in `config/database.yml` - everything such as usernames, passwords etc should be set via `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` for security reasons and to avoid developer wars.